# How to succesfuly train test split to train a model at keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, model

Im pretty new to keras so i've been struggling for a while to figure out how I should train - test split my data.

So my plan is to do sentiment analysis and here is my data:

```
df1
Columns: Sentence , Emotion, BackendSum
         bla1...    0-6      tensor(float32)
         bla2...    0-6      tensor(float32)
```

**Where emotion 0-6 are the emotions (Fear, anger etc.. ) Which I transformed to numbers**

And I have another data set which has text and backend sum and I want to classify the emotion of it:

```
df2
Columns: Sentence, BackendSum
         fla1...   tensor(float32)
         fla2...   tensor(float32)

inputs = keras.Input(shape=(300,))
x = layers.Dense(100, activation="relu", name="dense_1")(inputs)
x = layers.Dense(200, activation="relu", name="dense_2")(x)
outputs = layers.Dense(6, activation="sigmoid", name="predictions")(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)




model.fit(xtrain, ytrain,
         validation_data=(xtest,ytest),
         epochs = 200,
         batch_size=50)
```

> What is the correct way to fit my model? And to split my data so that I can train on df1 and test on df2

Comment: It seems that df1 is the train and validation dataset and df2 is the test dataset? You don't need to split between df1 and df2, you need to split df1 into training and validation sets for your model to train off of. To do this you can make use of keras' `validation_split` function in your `model.fit`. See here https://keras.rstudio.com/reference/fit.html.

Comment: I want to classify the df2 sentences to a specific emotion based on the training of the keras model. Which will be done from df1

Comment: Yes so training the model will solely be done on `df1`, as `df2` has no labels (category). Once the model has been trained on `df1`, you can use `model.predict()` on `df2` to classify them.

Comment: My target df1 (labes) are one hot encoding numpy array : [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] But I get an error when I try to fit: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).

Comment: Labels do not need to be an one hot encoding array as they are not fed into the neural network. There is nothing wrong with keeping the layers integers/strings from 0 -> 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sklearn.

```
  x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.1)
```

x are the 2d ndarray of the features, y are the 2d ndarray of the labels and test_size is the size of the data to be split in percentages (0.1 = 10%).

Comment: But in this way I have y_train and y_test df1 but I want to train on df1 and predict on df2

Comment: @AlexRika df1 should be split into testing and validation sets. then using the model you can predict df2. Try converting to a tensor using  tf.convert_to_tensor.